# Is it safe to use a QObject as a class member and use that member as the context for connect?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

I have a "normal" (non-qt derived) class. It is getting a QObject reference passed into it. Inside this class I want to connect the inputted QObject signal with a lambda.
So far so good, everything works fine except when the object of my class is destroyed before the passed in QObject. The signal from the QObject now points to a lambda that doesn't exist anymore.

The usual way of doing this is that my class inherits from QObject and that it passes `this` as the context to `connect`. The connections will then be automatically destroyed by Qt code when my object dies.

One other way of solving this is to save the return result of connect, a `QMetaObject::Connection` and then in the destructor of my class call `QObject::disconnect(resultOfConnect)`.

Now how I wanted to solve it is like this:

```
class SomeQtDerivedClass : public QObject {...}

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(SomeQtDerivedClass& qtObject)
    {
        connect(&qtObject, &qtObject::someSignal, &m_QtObject, [](){blahblah})
    }
private:
    QObject m_QtObject;
}
```

I haven't seen this pattern used anywhere and I can't find anything in the official documentation about this approach. I don't want to inherit from QObject if I can use composition instead. I don't want to create the m_QtObject on the heap if I can create it on the stack. And I want the connection to be automatically destroyed if my class object is destroyed before the inputted QObject.

Will this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work fine (of course as long as you don't set a parent on `m_QtObject`); `m_QtObject` gets destroyed with your class (after the user-provided destructor, if any), so it's almost no different than if you derived from `QObject` (indeed a base class from many points of view is really similar to a hidden first class member).

That being said, I would use `QMetaObject::Connection` (possibly wrapping it into a `std::unique_ptr` or something to get auto-disconnection on destruction); `QObject` is quite heavyweight, using it just to exploit its auto-disconnect features seems a bit of a waste.

Comment: Even setting parent is fine, as long as you make sure parent does not get to delete the object (either by making parent live longer than the child, or by removing the parent from the child before parent gets destructed).

Comment: `QObject` is quite heavyweight. Could you please add some details to this?

Comment: @vuko_zrno: essentially, what @BenjaminT said. A `QObject` requires at least a heap allocation (as it's PIMPL-based) of more than 100 bytes of memory, plus it contains all kind of extra stuff (parent/children links, timers, property maps, ...) which may require even more allocations. If you don't need its stuff, don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but it answers a misconception of @vuko_zrno.

Having a `QObject` as a member (by opposition to `QObject *`) does not guarantee you stack allocation. It only guarantees you that the QObject will be using the same memory chunk than the `MyClass` instance owning it.

For instance if you do `MyClass obj;` then both MyClass and the QObject will be on stack. But if you do `MyClass * obj = new MyClass;`, they will both be on heap.

Also something very important, Qt classes make heavy use of the pimpl design pattern. Meaning that the `QObject` class is just an empty shell and all its member variables are stored in another class named `QObjectPrivate`.

In practice the size of `QObject` is 16 bytes on 64-bit while `QObjectPrivate` 112 bytes. And `QObjectPrivate` will always be allocated on the heap.

So in practice I am not sure that having `QObject` vs `QObject *` makes any meaningful difference.

Comment: Thanks. I should have been more clear with the part that MyClass is also on the stack per default. About your comment on no meaningful difference. I assume that few bytes on the stack or heap will not have any significant performance difference. Just following the good practice to not use something that I don't have to. If I don't need to explicitly use heap for the purpose than I will not deviate from the default stack usage.